# Find explicit formula for generating function

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I'm given the following recurrence:

$a_0 = 3, a_n = 2a_{n-1} - 7$ for $n \ge 1$.

I did the following steps:

$$A(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$$

$$a_n = 2a_{n-1} - 7$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n = 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n-1}x^n - 7\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n$$

$$A(x) - a_0 = ?$$

Also I believe that $ 7\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n = 7 \cdot (\frac{1}{1-x} - 1)$ Is that correct?

I'm not sure how to continue with the right side further. Could you provide me with further steps?

// EDIT

$$A(x) - 3 = 2xA(x) + 7 - \frac{7}{1-x}$$
$$A(x) - 10 +  \frac{7}{1-x} = 2xA(x)$$

$$\require{cancel}
\cancel{\frac{A(x)-10}{2x} + \frac{7}{2x(1-x)} = A(x)}$$

//EDIT2

$$(2x-1)A(x) = \frac{7}{1-x}-10$$
$$A(x) = \frac{10x-3}{(1-x)(2x-1)}$$

$$A(x) = \frac{10x-3}{1-x} * \frac{1}{2x-1}$$

Now I can calculate the explicit formula for $a_n$.
Do I have to use the partial fractions or what are the steps now?

Comment: Hint: $$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {a_{n - 1} x^n }  = x\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {a_{n - 1} x^{n - 1} }  = x\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {a_k x^k }  = xA(x)
$$

Comment: Hint: solve the equation for $A(x)$. Instead of dividing through by $2x$ in your last step, subtract $A(x)$ from both sides: $ - 10 + \frac{7}{{1 - x}} = (2x - 1)A(x)$. Can you finish?

Comment: @Gary Thank you, I have missed that step. Now I advanced further and can now calculate the formula for $a_n$, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The goal is to be able to express every series either in the form:

- of a known power series, or
- as $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n x^n$ for some constants $b_n$ (and hopefully relate it to $A(x)$)

The best ways to handle this are through differentiation or various algebraic manipulations.

---

For example, consider the summation
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_{n-2} x^n
$$
provided $A(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$. We would naturally want to rewrite this to use $a_n$ instead. Well, a reindexing shows
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_{n-2} x^n
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n} x^{n+2}
$$
This seems vaguely correct, but that $n+2$ in the exponent isn't helpful. However...
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n} x^{n+2}
= x^2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n} x^{n}
= x^2 A(x)
$$

---

Another example: suppose we have the sum
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n x^{n-1}
$$
This constant $n$ just *screams* a differentiation to me. We note that
$$
\frac{d}{dx} a_n x^n = na_n x^{n-1}
$$
so
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n x^{n-1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{d}{dx} na_n x^{n-1}
= \frac{d}{dx} \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n = A'(x)
$$
Note that the $n=0$ term gets added back in, since it's a constant term.

---

> $7\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n = 7 \cdot (\frac{1}{1-x} - 1)$

This is correct. You're using the geometric series, after all:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n
= -1 + \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n
= -1 + \frac{1}{1-x}
$$

Comment: Thank you for the algebraic manipulations explanation. I've edited the question where I got stuck further. I still got the A(x) on both sides of the equation

Comment: @popcorn just try to write equation such that $A(x)= ...$ by making alone $A(x)$, the expansion of the rest will give you the recurrence relation

Comment: @NotaSalmonFish I think I did that in the last step, however I got A(x) on both sides? And if I convert it to one side it still won't be only $A(x) = ...$

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you finished the recurrence relation part,but stuck in partial fractions. You found that $$A(x) = \frac{10x-3}{1-x} \times \frac{1}{2x-1}$$

Then, let try to write it using [partial fractions decomposition](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/partialfractions.aspx) from calculus class:

$$A(x) = \frac{10x-3}{1-x} \times \frac{1}{2x-1} = \frac{4}{2x-1}- \frac{7}{x-1}$$

$$[x^n]A(x)=[x^n] \bigg( \frac{7}{1-x}- \frac{4}{1-2x}\bigg)= (7\times 1^n) -(4 \times2^n)$$

Comment: Thank you for the heads up with the partial fractions. It's understandable now. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe how complex the proffered solutions are for a recurrence that can literally be solved by inspection. What are you going to do when you have a $2^{nd}$-order recurrence with inhomogeneous terms such as $A^n$ and $n^2$? Anyway, here's the solution, which you can use to check your result.

Given

$$
a_n = 2a_{n-1} - 7,\quad a_0 = 3
$$

Assume

$$
a_n=f_n+b
$$

Substituting in the above you see that

$$
\begin{align}
&b=7;\\
&f_n=2f_{n-1}; f_0=a_0-b;\\
&a_n=-4\cdot2^n+7
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Not a downvote, but to my mind the solutions are less complex than they are _thorough_; they provide a clear procedure for solving equations of this type that can be used to solve other equations of the same type and can be generalized to the sort of more complicated situations you're talking about.